# global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getstreamChannelGroup camera index out of range (problem show in terminal)

Tags: python, opencv, camera

```
from collections import UserString
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Test",img)
    if not ret:
        break
    t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    print("Image"+t+"saved")
    count += 1
k = cv2.waitKey(5000) & 0xff
#k = cv2.waitKey(1)
if k%256 == 27:
    print("Close...")
    break
elif k%256 == 32:
    print("image"+str(count)+"saved")
    file ='Users/pushpakmandi/desktop/Capture_image'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite('./Users/pushpakmandi/Documents/file', img)
    count +=1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm trying to connect cannon EOS 80D via python OpenCV and then try to operate camera and capture image.

This is my Terminal Show:

```
[ERROR:e@0.067] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor:: getstreamChannelGroup camera index out of range 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"c:\Users\user\Picture\testing Folder\testing file",line 8, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215: Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.hight>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```